# Combinatorics floral arrangement question

Tags: combinatorics

A florist has to make a floral arrangement. She has 6 Banksias, 5 wattles and 4 Waratahs. All the flowers of each kind are different. In how many ways can the florist make a bunch of 10 flowers if she has to use at least 3 of each kind? Please show working.

I have tried to use the combinations formula but have gotten two different answers - 1200 and 4800 depending on whether I do the first 9 and then the last flower or all at once.

Just an interesting problem I know and have not been able to figure out.

Comment: Can you find how many possibilities there are if she takes $4$ Banksias, $3$ Wattles and $3$ Waratahs? Then the same for $(3,4,3)$ and $(3,3,4)$. Addition does the rest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At least three of each kind means that $10=4+3+3=3+4+3=3+3+4$ and therefore the number of different bunches of $10$ flowers out of $6$ Banksias, $5$ Wattles and $4$ Waratahs should be
$$\binom{6}{4}\binom{5}{3}\binom{4}{3}+\binom{6}{3}\binom{5}{4}\binom{4}{3}+\binom{6}{3}\binom{5}{3}\binom{4}{4}=600+400+200=1200.$$
We get $4800$ if we choose the first $9$ and then we add the last one (the **fourth** of the same kind): 
$$\binom{6}{3}\binom{5}{3}\binom{4}{3}\cdot (3+2+1)=4800$$
But here we overcount each bunch **four** times because each of the four flowers of the same kind can be the last one. So we have to divide $4800$ by $\mathbf{4}$ and we obtain again the correct number $1200$.

Comment: If we select 9 flowers as specified and then choose the 1 from remaining, the answer comes out to be 4800. Have I done over counting or any other mistake?

Comment: @DivyaPrakashSinha See my edit.

Comment: Could you please clarify how 4800 is over counting?

Comment: @global05 Let $B_1,\dots B_6$ the six Banksias. If we choose first $B_1,B_2,B_4$ and then $B_5$ we get the same bunch by taking first  $B_2,B_4,B_5$ and then $B_1$...